# How to get distinct record from mysql table?

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table **student** like this

```
id | name | zip 
1  | abc  | 1234
2  | xyz  | 4321
3  | asd  | 1234
```

I want to get all records but zip code should not be repeated. So In case of above table records, record No 1 and 2 should be fetched. Record No. 3 will not be fetched because it has a zip code which is already in record No. 1

Comment: "I want to get all records" conflicts with "Record number 3 must not be fetched". Do you want all records or a unique set of `zip` with the first record having that value?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT fieldName FROM tableName;
```

The following query will only select distinct 'zip' field.

```
SELECT DISTINCT zip FROM student;
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM tableName GROUP BY fieldName;
```

The following query will select all fields along with distinct zip field.

```
SELECT * FROM student GROUP BY zip;
```

Comment: What is the difference between `SELECT DISTINCT zip FROM tableName;` and `SELECT DISTINCT FROM tableName;` Result may be different for these two ???

Comment: Field name should be provided after DISTINCT. It was a typo before.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT FROM tableName; will give SQL syntax error. SELECT DISTINCT fieldName FROM tableName; is the correct one.

Comment: How this query will show **records** is above me. Even more above is how it gets 5 upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

TRY

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(zip),id,name FROM student;
```

OR

```
  SELECT * FROM student GROUP BY zip;
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(zip),id,name FROM student; will not work. It will show duplicate zip if id or name are unique.

Comment: Is there any solution for `SELECT DISTINCT(zip),id,name FROM student;` ?? so it can appear `ID`

Answer (score 5):

Altough in MySQL you can get away with:

```
SELECT *
FROM student
GROUP BY zip
```

I would choose:

```
SELECT * 
FROM student t
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT MIN(id) AS minid
      FROM student
      GROUP BY zip
    ) AS grp
    ON grp.minid = t.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Since presumably the other columns are of some interest....

```
 SELECT y.*
 FROM yourTable y,
 (SELECT MIN(y2.id)
  FROM yourTable y2
  GROUP BY y2.zip) ilv
 WHERE ilv.id=y.id;
```

(or you could use the [max-concat trick](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html))

**update**

Oracle have now removed the max concat trick from the linked page - but it is [described](https://forum.hardware.fr/hfr/Programmation/mysql-concat-explication-sujet_8491_1.htm) elsewhere [on](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Z3ciBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT182&lpg=PT182&dq=max%20concat%20trick&source=bl&ots=6EHUQXyjy7&sig=SNG8HqRMB_79EKLTZJtw0GHgJsk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF4MvIxqjcAhVIBMAKHYKADIkQ6AEITjAD#v=onepage&q=max%20concat%20trick&f=false) the [internet](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Comment: You miss a comma after `yourTable y`

Answer (score 0):

Is there any problem if I use as this below?

```
select distinct zip,name,id from student;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
Select Distinct(zip),id,name group by zip;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select id, name, distinct(zip) from student;
```