# PHP - MYSQL - Avoid counting duplicated elements

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to avoid to display the elements that have the same name.

For example my table is:

```
+----------+----------------------+
|   name   |       category       |
+----------+----------------------+
|   AAA    |         Sport        |
+----------+----------------------+
|   BBB    |          City        |
+----------+----------------------+
|   CCC    |         Sport        |
+----------+----------------------+
|   DDD    |          Sun         |
+----------+----------------------+
|   EEE    |         Sport        |
+----------+----------------------+
|   FFF    |          Sun         |
+----------+----------------------+
```

How can I get an array of `category` elements avoiding repetitions?

Output Array:

```
["Sport", "City", "Sun"]
```

My Code is:

```
<?php

      $return_arr = array();

      $sql="SELECT * FROM $DB_table";

      $resultCat = $conn->query($sql);     


      while($row = $resultCat->fetch_assoc()) {

           $category = $row['category'];
           $row_array['category'] = $row['category'];

           array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
           echo "<option value=$category>$category</option>";

     }
?>
```

Comment: `select distinct category from t`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get distinct record from mysql table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109758/how-to-get-distinct-record-from-mysql-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM #DB_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

try using select distinct

```
 select distinct category from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select DISTINCT category from your_table group by category;
```